# InstallData Attribute showing only on the frontend and not in customer_entity table

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute

I have created a module with setup/installdata.php and layout & template files, but the custom attribute is showing up only on the frontside on customer account create form. Am i missing something?

```
    <?php
    namespace NameSpace\NameSpace\Setup;

    use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }
    /**
     * Installs DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $entityTypeId = $customerSetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY);
        $customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "reg_code");

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "reg_code",  array(
            "type"      => "varchar",
            "backend"   => "",
            "label"     => "Company Reg. code",
            "input"     => "text",
            "source"    => "",
            "visible"   => true,
            "required"  => false,
            "default"   => "",
            "frontend"  => "",
            "unique"    => false,
            "note"      => ""
        ));

        $reg_code   = $customerSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "reg_code");
        $reg_code = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'reg_code');

        $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
        $used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
        $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
        $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
        $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $used_in_forms[]="customer_address";
        $used_in_forms[]="customer_address_edit";

        $reg_code->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
            ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
            ->setData("is_system", 0)
            ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
            ->setData("is_visible", 1)
            ->setData("sort_order", 121);

        $reg_code->save();

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: could you add your installData.php file code and also where do you want to show that attribute ? ( on which area )

Comment: if you created extension_attributes you cant find in database.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't show up in `customer_entity` table.

**It will show up at `Eav Attribute`table in your DB.**

If you can find your attribute at customer edit form at back end than you have done correct things no issue with it.

I don't know what's your mistake. Could you please try with below code. Its working for me.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\GroupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;



class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
protected $groupFactory;
protected $customerSetupFactory;
private $attributeSetFactory;
private $eavSetupFactory;


public function __construct(GroupFactory $groupFactory,EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
    AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory) {

    $this->groupFactory = $groupFactory;
    $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory; 
}

public function install(
    ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
    ModuleContextInterface $context
) {

    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $setup->startSetup();
    $attributesInfo = [
        'customer_avatar' => [
            'label' => 'Company Reg. code',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'input' => 'text',
            'position' => 1000,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'system' => 0,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'position' => 1000,
        ]
    ];
    $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
    $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
    /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
    $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
    $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
    foreach ($attributesInfo as $attributeCode => $attributeParams) {
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode, $attributeParams);
    }
    $magentoUsernameAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'company_reg_code');
    $magentoUsernameAttribute->addData([
        'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
        'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
        'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','customer_account_edit','adminhtml_checkout','adminhtml_customer_address','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address'],
    ]);
    $magentoUsernameAttribute->save();

        $setup->endSetup();
}

}

?>
```

**Note : After update code remember that you need to remove your module entry from `setup_module` table than run below commands from your Magento root.**

```
setup:upgrade
setup:static-content:deploy (If you are on Magento 2.2.x than you need to add -f at end of command)
```

Hope it will resolve your issue.!!

Comment: its not showing up even in eav_attribute table and customer edit form at back end. its showing only in the frontend.

Comment: @kapsid, Please update your question with code, So that i can guide you.

Comment: i have added the code

Comment: @kapsid, Check my updated code.

Comment: @kapsid, if it works for you than give up vote to help community. !!

Comment: there is no setup_module table in database.

Comment: @kapsid, Are you using Magento 2.x ?, try to search in your DB with `setup_`

Comment: im using magento 2.2.3. there is no table with setup_ or similar table.